# Semidirect Products with GAP

Tags: group-theory, computer-algebra-systems, gap, semidirect-product

I'm wondering how to specify to GAP which homomorphism to use when constructing a semidirect product. I'm trying to have it construct $\left(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\right)\rtimes_\varphi S_3$. Since $\mathrm{Aut}\left(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\right)\cong GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, I want to specify $\varphi:S_3\rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}\left(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\right)$ as $\varphi:S_3\rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ element by element (i.e. give a 2x2 matrix for each element of $S_3$).

I want to do this just to do group element multiplications quickly. I'll obviously specify $p$ when necessary.

I'm fairly new to GAP so a low-level answer (or reference) would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking the [Gap Manual](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/GAP-Manual/index.html) specifically the section on [semi-direct products](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/GAP-Manual/SemidirectProduct.html)? It looks like you might be able to do what you want with [this function](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Software/GAP-Manual/GroupHomomorphismByImages.html).

Comment: Thanks @JacobSchlather, I'll read those pages and post a solution if I can figure it out. Others are of course still welcome to help :)

Comment: I noticed you still don't have an answer.  You might get a quicker response if you email your question to the gap forum: forum@gap-system.org

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case you still don't have an answer:
You want to use the GAP command
`SemidirectProduct( <g>, <hom>, <n> )`.
Here, `<hom>` is a group homomorphism from the group `<g>` to the automorphism group of the group `<n>`.
In GAP this might look like this (for $p=7$):

```
gap> h := CyclicGroup(7);;
gap> g := DirectProduct( h, h );;
gap> aut := AutomorphismGroup( g );;
gap> iso := IsomorphismGroups( GL(2,7), aut );;
gap> s := SymmetricGroup(3);;
gap> GeneratorsOfGroup( s );
[ (1,2,3), (1,2) ]
gap> hom := GroupHomomorphismByImages( s, GL(2,7), GeneratorsOfGroup( s ), [ a, b ] );
[ (1,2,3), (1,2) ] -> [ [ [ Z(7)^0, 0*Z(7) ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^0 ] ], [ [ Z(7)^0, 0*Z(7) ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^0 ] ] ]
```

`a` and `b` are your favourite images of `(1,2,3)` and `(1,2)`, respectively. I chose `One(GL(2,7))` because I'm lazy. Note that you have to tell GAP that your matrices are over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Fortunately, that can be done like this:

```
gap> a := [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ] * One( GF(7) ); 
[ [ Z(7)^0, Z(7)^2 ], [ Z(7), Z(7)^4 ] ]
gap> a in GL(2,7);
true
```

Now you can compose `hom` and `iso` and define your semidirect product:

```
gap> semi := SemidirectProduct( s, CompositionMapping( iso, hom ), g );
<pc group with 4 generators>
```